# Test if port open and forwarded using PHP

Tags: php, portforwarding

Full Disclosure:  There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161976/check-if-client-port-is-open-and-forwarded-c-asp-net).

Is there any way I can test if a particular port is open and forwarded properly using PHP? Specifically, how do I go about using a socket to connect to a given user with a given port?

An Example of this is in the 'Custom Port Test' section of [WhatsMyIP.org/ports](http://www.whatsmyip.org/ports/).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by being "forwarded properly", but hopefully this example will do the trick:

```
$host = 'stackoverflow.com';
$ports = array(21, 25, 80, 81, 110, 443, 3306);

foreach ($ports as $port)
{
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);

    if (is_resource($connection))
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($port, 'tcp') . ') is open.</h2>' . "\n";

        fclose($connection);
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
stackoverflow.com:21 is not responding.
stackoverflow.com:25 is not responding.
stackoverflow.com:80 (http) is open.
stackoverflow.com:81 is not responding.
stackoverflow.com:110 is not responding.
stackoverflow.com:443 is not responding.
stackoverflow.com:3306 is not responding.
```

---

**See http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers for a complete list of port numbers.**

Comment: Thanks - this is very similar to what I was expecting to do.  When I said 'forwarded properly' I meant that the user has port forwarding enabled on their router for the port I wish to use.  I have a multiplayer game which has the option to act as a server.  Hence, port forwarding is needed and we would like to have a simple feature that tries to verify that the port is, in fact, forwarded.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this tests your outbound and the receivers inbound, so if you wanted to write a function to just test your outbound, you need to find a public server with all inbound ports being open?

Comment: This is perfect, worked wonders for me and replaced my cURL solution which hardly worked. Gem!

Comment: Also useful to set timout `$connection = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);` [php.net/fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen)

Answer (score -1):

```yaml
  xxxxx-fpm:
    image: ....
    healthcheck:
      # Check until the FPM port is in in the LISTEN list
      # test: ["CMD-SHELL", "netstat -an | grep -q -F \":9000\""]
      # Or use php to test php since the non alpine fpm image has no binary able to know if a port is in listen mode
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "php -r '$$c = @fsockopen(\"localhost\", 9000); if (is_resource($$c)) { fwrite(STDOUT, \"OK\"); fclose($$c); exit(0); } else { fwrite(STDERR, \"FAIL\"); exit(1); }'"]
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 30
      start_period: 10s
```