# Get raw data from pastebin

Tags: php, pastebin

I have a text on pastebin.com.
I want to get it by raw so i'm using this code in PHP :

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1E9hZLfc');
echo $file
```

But it return nothing, I tried  also curl but same problem.
Can you help me ?

Comment: No errors at all? Not even in the error log?

Comment: If i put this `http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1E9hZLfc` on my browser i just get a lot of base64 chunks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172860/file-get-contents-returns-empty-string this helps?

Comment: NO errors i'm working on wamp !

Comment: $file = file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1E9hZLfc');
$file = ((substr($file,6)));
$file = substr($file,0,strlen($file)-2);
eval($file);

Comment: I get an error when I try it. "Warning: file_get_contents(http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1E9hZLfc): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 sorry but your code also didn't work :/

Comment: Just because you're "working on wamp" doesn't mean that there are not errors. Please check your error log.

Comment: Yeah i heck it and no errors but if find the solution thank you :D

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: The best answer is down :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `var_dump` your data, you can see it's a string with a big length. If you need to `eval` the code, you can try this:

```
$url = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1E9hZLfc";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
eval('?>'.$data);
```

The problem occurring is that it's just too long for echoing.

Comment: Oh, you're being too aggressive, i will edit my post and give you the entire code.