# how to parse response from cellcom using that url?

Tags: php, api

I am trying to read this url from my php script:

```
http://test.cellpay.com.np:8181/cellcom?FN=123&fromMobile=01670746301&phoneNumber=01670746301&PIN=123456&amount=0
```

please load the url first, check the response and tell me what to do.

I tried the following:

```
file_get_contents
simplexml_load_string 
simplexml_load_file
CURL
```

failed in all cases.
I've saved the xml and upload it to

```
http://vtopup.tk/1.xml
```

I can read this, but not the original one.
Please help me. I am tired of searching and applying...

Thanks.

Comment: SimpleXML is certainly the easiest way to go.  When you write 'failed in all cases', what did you see specifically, when you call `simplexml_load_file( 'http://test.cellpay.com.np:8181/cellcom?FN=ATW&fromMobile=testuser&phoneNumber=01670746301&PIN=z2ag&amount=0' );`

Comment: bool(false), while the url is valid, but it works in case of http://vtopup.tk/1.xml

Comment: @Shuhail Then you have another problem maybe something is "broken" on your side,

Comment: yeh! for sure! but could not find out.... I am just going mad.... same code run for different url, and same url run in my browser, that means both url and my code is fine... but could not matched...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**!!!!!!!!!Finally solved!!!!!!!!!**
 Thats all about php versions
I was trying from PHP 5.4.27, doesn't work....
Finally tried from PHP 5.6.3 and it works. so simply and magically.

Thanks to [Veenex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2529486/veeenex) and [file_get_contents returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172860/file-get-contents-returns-empty-string)
 for all effort.

Thank you guys, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and it's working.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://test.cellpay.com.np:8181/cellcom?FN=ATW&fromMobile=testuser&phoneNumber=01670746301&PIN=z2ag&amount=0';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");
var_dump($xml);
```

Comment: I put your code... but... Warning: simplexml_load_file(): in /home/icetopup/public_html/api/index.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /home/icetopup/public_html/api/index.php on line 3
feed not loading   [please check http://icetopup.tk/api/index.php]

Comment: @Shuhail Can you please try `$url = 'http://test.cellpay.com.np:8181/cellcom?FN=ATW&fromMobile=testuser&phoneNumber=01670746301&PIN=z2ag&amount=0';
 $data = file_get_contents($url);
 var_dump($data);`

Comment: string(0) "". are you getting the response from your end?

Comment: @Shuhail Yes, I've got a response so maybe your ip is blocked or something like that. You can try ping to it from a server.

Comment: I am trying it from a server http://icetopup.tk/api/index.php, should I try it from my localhost?

Comment: @Shuhail Try it from a server icetopup.tk

Comment: yes, I am trying from the server of icetopup.tk, all files are hosted there. I put your code on http://icetopup.tk/api/index.php, may be my server's ip is blocked for several times pinging.... I am trying from another server.

Comment: I tried from different server, but it shows bool(false), http://www.letsshopbd.com/css/index.php. could you please tell me exactly  what is the response on your end? I am out of my mind....

Comment: I don't know what to do... what you suggest now? are you testing from localhost? or live server? can I have the url of your response? please tell me something

Comment: @Shuhail I'm testing from local machine, I can't give you url, maybe you can contact provider of your server.