# file_get_contents("php://input") is empty if the POST body is above ~16 000 characters

Tags: php

I've got an application that sends relatively large POST requests to an Apache shared hosting.

On the server, there's a `.php` file with

```php
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

that's supposed to read the POST raw body. It works as long as the POST body is less than ~16000 characters in length. If there are more, the above piece of code returns an empty string.

I'd like to have the entire body returned, regardless of its length.

- By default, it is said there's a `post_max_size = 64M` setting in the server's `php.ini`. Setting it myself manually doesn't alleviate the issue.
- The client-side code always works properly. The Content-Length header is set correctly as well.
- Sending the POST via a HTML form and accessing it with $_POST['content'] server-side behaves in the same exact way.

Comment: Who hosts the server? Is it a hosting company that has set a limit that you cannot alter in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create an empty folder named `tmp` in the public root.
In most cases it most likely would be created automatically (if needed at all), however this hosting company's configuration is flawed, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The problme might be with the web server.
You may try to up the body limit on your web server software.
For example in Apache :

```
LimitRequestBody
```

in Nginx :

```
client_max_body_size
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this all the way on top of your script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You are most likely getting an error that you cannot see due to errors being disabled.

You can also try removing `--with-curlwrapper` from the PHP configuration and rebuilding it.
[file_get_contents returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172860/file-get-contents-returns-empty-string)