# PHP script what checks ftp servers are online?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to write a php script which is called by a setInterval( "ajaxrequest('ftp.php', 'context')", 1000 ); function. The php script is fairly easy. It's countain an array of ftp addresses. It loop the array and check every ip address that is online or not.

Here is a sample code of the php script:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("192.168.1.108",21,1) or die ("Cannot connect to the server");
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

So basically what happens here: We have a javascript which calling a php script every second to check that the ftp servers are online or not. In the PHP script try to connect that if it cant it wrote out "Cannot connect to the server" then it closes the connection.

My problem is that i have to do this way, do not have any chance to use it by cron job because we need to check it trough a web page that the servers are online or not in real time. But in this way somewhere there is a memory leak its eats my memory really fast.

Is there any way that i can release the memory or solve this problem in an other way?

Comment: Use fsockopen() instead. Also, here is a related answer of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226374/test-if-port-open-and-forwarded-using-php

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
it's unforunately not solving the problem here is how i made it:

$conn_id = fsockopen("192.168.1.108", 21, $errno, $errstr, 1) or die ("Cannot connect to the server");
fclose($conn_id); 
and still have the memory issue although it starts a little bit later then with the ftp_connect() function

Comment: try reading here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: The memory problem is probably related to requesting a check every second on many IPs. This is over kill, why every second? FTP servers are pretty much online 99.9% of the time, How many IPs are you checking?

Comment: so its basically can be any servers in range 10 - 200. 1 second because they want to see in real time is there any problem with the servers.

Comment: These are they own servers thats why they want to check upon them.

Comment: I also read  php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php  and tried that way as well but this is also eating memory really fast.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can increase the duration of these callbacks and still show a valid real time data. 1 minute isn't that bad, even the one's with all the patience won't keep eye on the screen every second and ultimately the resource consumption will be reduced by 60 times less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**consider this answer to be a suggestion and direction**, I never had to do such things, but if i wore to face it.

I would write a cron, that will scan the ftp port over an ip. This cron will run once every minute. The ftp's that are not responding will be kept in db.

I would make ajax requests to the php only to retrieve those data from the table.

What this will do is allow to asynchronously execute the two major tasks

- List all ftp's not responding
- update user with the list of ftp's not responding

Also, your method will have to find out list of ftp's not working for every instance, and this will put even more strain on the server when multiple requests will be made. This way will make the resource hungry execution once, which will be valid for all :D

hope this helps...

**EDIT** not sure if this adresses your cron dilemma, but do update

Comment: Thank you very much this is idea is looking really nice so far i'm going to try it. I think now i understand why is my app is so memory hungry really appreciate for your advise.