# how to check ports 2082 and 2222 with php for detecting server's control panel

Tags: php

How can i check ports 2082, 2222 with php to detect control panel of server?

```
$ports = array(2082 => 'cpanel', 2222 => 'directadmin' , ....);
$panel = "";

foreach($ports as $port => $panelName){
   // some codes for checking the port's
   // if(something)
         $panel = $panelName;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can draw some inspiration from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2226759/1568684

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if port open and forwarded using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226374/test-if-port-open-and-forwarded-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

there is no straight forward solution for this, you need to implement your own creative method. you may need to detect one control panel with opening socket,while other using an specific file existence (ex. Cpanel puts api files on php include path) or any other idea.

you can use this class for this purpose

```
namespace Model;

// usage:
//include 'detectControlPanel';
//$object = new \model\detectControlPanel();
//$result = $object->getDetect();
//var_dump($result);

class detectControlPanel
{
public $debug = false;
protected $detect = array();

public function getDetect()
{
    return $this->detect;
}

public function __construct($debug = false)
{
    $this->run();
    $this->debug = $debug;
    $this->debug($this->detect);
}

public function run()
{
    $this->detect['cpanel'] = $this->isCpanel();
    $this->detect['virtualmin'] = $this->isVirtualmin();
    $this->detect['plesk'] = $this->isPlesk();
    $this->detect['directadmin'] = $this->isDirectadmin();
    return $this->detect;
}

private function isCpanel()
{
    try {
        $this->telnet('localhost', 2082);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->debug($ex);
        return false;
    }
}

private function isVirtualmin()
{
    try {
        $this->telnet('localhost', 10000);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->debug($ex);
        return false;
    }
}

private function isDirectadmin()
{
    try {
        $this->telnet('localhost', 2222);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->debug($ex);
        return false;
    }
}

private function isPlesk()
{
    try {
        $this->telnet('localhost', 8443);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->debug($ex);
        return false;
    }
}

private function debug($input)
{
    if ($this->debug == true) {
        if (gettype($input) == 'string') {
            echo '<br>' . "\n";
            echo $input;
            echo '<br>' . "\n";
        } elseif (gettype($input) == 'array') {
            echo '<pre>' . "\n";
            print_r($input);
            echo '</pre>' . "\n";
        } elseif (gettype($input) == 'object' && get_class($input) == 'Exception') {
            echo '<pre>' . "\n";
            echo $input->getMessage();
            echo '</pre>' . "\n";
        } else {
            var_dump($input);
        }
    }
}

private function telnet($hostname, $port)
{
    if (!$hostname)
        throw new \Exception("empty host name");
    if (!$port)
        throw new \Exception("empty port number");
    $ipAddress = gethostbyname($hostname);
    $link = @fsockopen($ipAddress, $port, $errno, $error);
    if ($error) {
        throw new \Exception($error, $errno);
    }
    if ($link) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```