# Connection refused when using fsockopen

Tags: php, fsockopen

Code:

```
$domain="173.15.180.86";
echo fsockopen($domain, 5904);
```

The code gives connection refused error. Although when checking on http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ the port is opened. What could be the reason of it?

Purpose: I want to check whether port is open or dead

Comment: What is the purpose of your code?

Comment: I just want to know whether port is open or dead.

Comment: Then you may have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226374/test-if-port-open-and-forwarded-using-php)

Comment: @JoffreyCarle I tried the same. Getting "173.15.180.86:5904 is not responding"